# Calculated Fields in Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am looking to add a custom calculated field to my POWER PIVOT

Store 1
Product Category 1 - 10
Product Category 2 - 10
Store 2
Product Category 1 - 12
Product Category 2 - 13
Store 3
Product Category 1 - 12
Product Category 2 -14

I'm trying to calculate the mix % of a category, so for example, store one category 1 mix is 50% (10/20)

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In a Pivot Table, I would right-click any measure cell and choose Show As / % of Parent Row Total.